# (Re-)Create GPT from existing partitions on Debian 8

Tags: gpt, partition-table

On my Debian 8 server HDD /dev/sda crashed. `mdadm` informed me via email and I had the disk replaced.

After the server was back up I copied over my GPT from using `sgdisk -R /dev/sdb /dev/sda`. The second I hit "Enter" on my keyboard I realized my mistake.

So now I have an empty GPT on both disks.

My question is if it is possible to re-create the GPT on `/dev/sdb` as the server is still running as I did not reboot since copying the wrong GPT?

I did a backup with `sfdisk -d /dev/sdb > sdb.partition.table` before the faulty HDD was replaced. But as I did not do a backup with `sgdisk` the backup is completely useless, if I am correct?

Additionally I have this output from *fdisk -l* from before copying the GPT:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 454774BD-960F-45C6-8C82-AE5C156444E0

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      4096   33558527   33554432   16G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb2  33558528   34607103    1048576  512M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3  34607104 5860533134 5825926031  2.7T Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4      2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/md0: 16 GiB, 17171349504 bytes, 33537792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/md1: 511.7 MiB, 536543232 bytes, 1047936 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/md2: 2.7 TiB, 2982739705856 bytes, 5825663488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a bit and after trying out tools such as *testdisk*, I did not find a defintive way to restore my original GPT on `/dev/sdb`

So I tried using *cgdisk* and it was successfull, as I still had the original "sector layout" of `/dev/sdb` noted down:

```
Disk identifier: 9F95A04D-3ECB-144D-B2A0-55CDD986072B

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      4096   33558527   33554432   16G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb2  33558528   34607103    1048576  512M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3  34607104 5860533134 5825926031  2.7T Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4      2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
```

With this information I created partitions with the same starting sectors, the same number of sectors used and the same file system types as stated above.

After writing the GPT on `/dev/sdb`, `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` gave me the same output as above.

I then copied over the GPT by using `sgdisk -R /dev/sda /dev/sdb` (this time in the correct order) and `fdisk -l /dev/sda` showed me the exact same "sector layout" for `/dev/sda` as for `/dev/sdb`:

```
Disk identifier: 4CB38488-8B72-44AA-8449-4E4692165893

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      4096   33558527   33554432   16G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb2  33558528   34607103    1048576  512M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3  34607104 5860533134 5825926031  2.7T Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4      2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
```

All that was left to do, was to resync the RAID-Volumes using *mdadm* and re-install grub2.
 
After resyncing was done, as mentioned, I re-installed grub2 on `/dev/sda` (I re-installed it `/dev/sdb` too, just to be sure) and generated a new devicemap. (I had to flush the HDD buffers to avoid the grub2 core image warnings, though)
 
I rebooted the server and it came up again just fine.
 
**IMPORTANT**: I only did this GPT tinkering because I have a complete backup of my server as I was not 100% sure this would work and I could have destroyed my partitions.